# Is it possible that Lightning Network payments may someday replace all Bitcoin transactions, rendering the block chain obsolete?

Tags: blockchain, lightning-network, scalability

To tackle the scalability problem of Bitcoin the lightning network was introduced, which (if I understand correctly) adds an additional layer to the blockchain, allowing users to create a payment channel between any two parties on those layers. Transactions on this channel will be fast and cost little or nothing.

Now my question is: Is it possible that Lightning Network payments may someday replace all Bitcoin transactions, rendering the block chain obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to join the lightning network, you will generally need to create and publish a bitcoin transaction.

Likewise, to reposition your funds in the lightning network, or to move bitcoin out of the lightning network, you will need to create and publish a bitcoin transaction.

So it doesn't really make sense to say that the lightning network will 'make the bitcoin blockchain obsolete'. Even if every single payment happened on the lightning network, **the bitcoin blockchain is still required, as it's liveness is what underpins the security of funds on the lightning network.** If the bitcoin blockchain disappears or stops functioning, then lightning too will cease to work.